# Text Field Not Updating

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to get the log on my program to update with every button press *see picture below, however it will only display the data on the first time it has been pressed. I'm not sure if that's because it's in a for loop.

[Initialise button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5CID.png)

stop();
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

```
var MAX_ORGANISMS: int = 12;
var MAX_GENES: int = 2;
var genotype: Array = new Array();
var MAX_PARENTS: int = 2; // number of parents organisms to select
var MAX_CHILDREN: int = 2; // number offspring per selected parent
var generation: int = 0; // to count the generation being shown
var list_selected: Array = new Array(); // list of selected org.
var number_selected: int;
var geno_text: String = "";

function random_genotype_initialisation(): void {
generation = 0;
number_selected = 0;
var org: int;
for (org = 0; org < MAX_ORGANISMS; org++) {
    list_selected[org] = 0;
    var genotype_1organism: Array = new Array();
    genotype_1organism[0] = randomRangeInteger(1, 4);
    // gene1 = head colour (4 types)
    genotype_1organism[1] = randomRangeInteger(46, 49);
    // gene2 = head width (44 - 48)
    genotype_1organism[2] = randomRangeInteger(50, 55);
    // gene3 = head legnth
    genotype_1organism[3] = randomRangeInteger(1, 4);
    // gene4 = eye type (4 types)
    genotype_1organism[4] = randomRangeInteger(30, 35);
    // gene5 = eye width (30 - 35)

    genotype_1organism[5] = randomRangeInteger(1, 4);
    // gene6 = nose type (4 types)
    genotype_1organism[6] = randomRangeInteger(10, 18);
    // gene7 = nose height (10 - 18)

    genotype[org] = genotype_1organism.slice();

}
}

function randomRangeInteger(min: int, max: int): int {
    var randomNum: int = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return randomNum;
}

function show_phenotype(): void {
var org: int;
var org_property: String;
for (org = 0; org < MAX_ORGANISMS; org++) {

    org_property = "o" + org + "_head";
    this[org_property].gotoAndStop(genotype[org][0]);
    this[org_property].width = genotype[org][1];
    this[org_property].height = genotype[org][2];

    org_property = "o" + org + "_eyes";
    this[org_property].gotoAndStop(genotype[org][3]);
    this[org_property].width = genotype[org][4];

    org_property = "o" + org + "_nose";
    this[org_property].gotoAndStop(genotype[org][5]);
    this[org_property].height = genotype[org][6];

    geno_text += "Geno" + org + " has initialised." + "This Geno has a " + genotype[org][1] + " by " + genotype[org][2] + " face" + "\n" ;
    geno_log.text = geno_text;

}
}

function initialise(event: MouseEvent) {
random_genotype_initialisation();
show_phenotype();
}

initialise_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, initialise);
```

The program has some faces, which change features randomly, each time the user presses the initialise button. Which by my knowledge shows that the button handler works, and the program is performing correctly, however, the text does not follow suit and only changes once.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question obviously misses the button handler. Then, this code you share with us should produce the very same result every time, so it works every time, but you don't see any changes because there are none. Probably.

Comment: I believe i have a button handler - see edit

Comment: Ok, now it calls **random_genotype_initialisation** that is not there, and the same **show_phenotype** function, which, as I said above, should produce the same result no matter how many times called.

Comment: Didn't think that the rest of the program was relevant (appended - see edit). Why does it not change? If the rest of the program such as the objects i created to change randomly each time the button is pressed works, then why not the text?

Comment: How big is your TextField? Does the new texts fit there as you never reset the `geno_text` variable? You can also simply `trace(geno_text);` after the loop to make sure it updates.

Comment: The text doesnt fit, you have to scroll. trace works but in the output viewer, still not updating the log on the stage.

Comment: So `geno_text` contains what expected, but `geno_log.text` wont update at all after the first run? What else do you have in this project? As this part really seems right and should work perfectly. How is the TextField wrapped if it's scrollable?

Comment: Added the rest of the program, really didn't think the entire program would need to be added; have a random number generator and declared variables at the start.

Comment: Did you have your TextField wrapped somehow if it's scrollable? Add `geno_text = "";` as the first line of your `initialise`-function and see if it then works how you ment it to work.

Comment: I set it to no wrap, and it prints to the textbox just fine. Do you want to add an answer so i can mark it as accepted, as i wouldnt have thought about the wrap without your comment. Thank man